# java framework source has a pattern that assigns instance variable to local variable

Tags: java, variables, frameworks, instance, local

So, `pop()`method in java framework `java.util.Stack` class looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public synchronized E pop() {
    if (elementCount == 0) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    final int index = --elementCount;
    final E obj = (E) elementData[index];
    elementData[index] = null;
    modCount++;
    return obj;
}
```

The part that I have trouble in understanding is local variable `index`. It seems we don't need it. `elementCount` is a instance variable in `Vector` class which `Stack` class extended.

**So my point is,**

```
    final int index = --elementCount;
    final E obj = (E) elementData[index];
    elementData[index] = null;
```

**These 3 lines of code can be written like**

```
    final E obj = (E) elementData[--elementCount];
    elementData[elementCount] = null;
```

which consumes less memory, because memory space for `index` local variable isn't used.

Also, I found this pattern along the java framework source code. For example `add(E Object)` method in `java.util.ArrayList` class looks :

```
@Override public boolean add(E object) {
    Object[] a = array;
    int s = size;
    if (s == a.length) {
        Object[] newArray = new Object[s +
                (s < (MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT / 2) ?
                 MIN_CAPACITY_INCREMENT : s >> 1)];
        System.arraycopy(a, 0, newArray, 0, s);
        array = a = newArray;
    }
    a[s] = object;
    size = s + 1;
    modCount++;
    return true;
}
```

in this example, `array` is a instance variable, and as you can see, a new local variable `a` is assigned to hold it.

Does anybody know about this? Big Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though this is a really old question, but I want to share some information I earned during my journey.

I could find some explanation about my question on [Performance Tips on Android](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#Loops) page. First see sample code from the page,

```
static class Foo {
    int mSplat;
}

Foo[] mArray = ...

public void zero() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; ++i) {
        sum += mArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void one() {
    int sum = 0;
    Foo[] localArray = mArray;
    int len = localArray.length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        sum += localArray[i].mSplat;
    }
}

public void two() {
    int sum = 0;
    for (Foo a : mArray) {
        sum += a.mSplat;
    }
}
```

According to the above page, zero() is slowest, one() is faster. Because ***it pulls everything out into local variables, avoiding the lookups.***

I think this explanation might solve my second question, which was asking "a new local variable `a` is assigned to hold it. but why?"

I hope this might help someone who have the same curiosity.

---

**[EDIT]** Let me add some details about "**lookups**".

So if you compile above code and disassembles the class file with [`javap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html) command with -c option, it will print out disassembled code, i.e., the instructions that comprise the Java bytecodes.

```
public void zero();
Code:
   0: iconst_0                          // Push int constant 0
   1: istore_1                          // Store into local variable 1 (sum=0)
   2: iconst_0                          // Push int constant 0
   3: istore_2                          // Store into local variable 2 (i=0)
   4: goto          22                  // First time through don't increment
   7: iload_1
   8: aload_0
   9: getfield      #14                 // Field mArray:[LTest$Foo;
  12: iload_2
  13: aaload
  14: getfield      #39                 // Field Test$Foo.mSplat:I
  17: iadd
  18: istore_1
  19: iinc          2, 1
  22: iload_2                           // Push value of local variable 2 (i)
  23: aload_0                           // Push local variable 0 (this)
  24: getfield      #14                 // Field mArray:[LTest$Foo;
  27: arraylength                       // Get length of array
  28: if_icmplt     7                   // Compare and loop if less than (i < mArray.length)
  31: return

public void one();
Code:
   0: iconst_0                          // Push int constant 0
   1: istore_1                          // Store into local variable 1 (sum=0)
   2: aload_0                           // Push this
   3: getfield      #14                 // Field mArray:[LTest$Foo;
   6: astore_2                          // Store reference into local variable (localArray)
   7: aload_2                           // Load reference from local variable
   8: arraylength                       // Get length of array
   9: istore_3                          // Store into local variable 3 (len = mArray.length)
  10: iconst_0                          // Push int constant 0
  11: istore        4                   // Store into local variable 4 (i=0)
  13: goto          29                  // First time through don't increment
  16: iload_1
  17: aload_2
  18: iload         4
  20: aaload
  21: getfield      #39                 // Field Test$Foo.mSplat:I
  24: iadd
  25: istore_1
  26: iinc          4, 1
  29: iload         4                   // Load i from local variable
  31: iload_3                           // Load len from local variable
  32: if_icmplt     16                  // // Compare and loop if less than (i < len)
  35: return
```

These instructions are a bit unfamiliar, so I looked up in [JVM spec documents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/index.html). (If you are curious, especially [chapter 3, Compiling for the Java Virtual Machine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.7), and [chapter 6, The Java Virtual Machine Instruction Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html) would be helpful).

I added comment to help you understand, **but in a nut shell, method `zero()` should operate `getfield` instruction on every iteration**. According to [JVM spec documentation 3.8. Working with Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.8) section, [`getfield`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.getfield) operation performs several jobs like below.

> The compiler generates symbolic references to the fields of an
>   instance, which are stored in the run-time constant pool. Those
>   run-time constant pool items are resolved at run-time to determine the
>   location of the field within the referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

`These 3 lines of code can be written like`

We're in the business of making a useful and extendable programs, and in order to acheive that we should make our life as Developers easy as we can.
If it takes me a 5 more seconds to read the code and i can simplify it, i would. Specially if it comes in the expense of a `int` memory.. hardly calls as Optimization.

`in this example, array is a instance variable, and as you can see, a new local variable a is assigned to hold it. Does anybody know about this?`

This is hardly calls as question, i believe you meant to phrase it like that:
`Why does they used another reference to array called a if they could use array ?`

Well, I truly can't see why, because they could have use the `E` type since it given to them. It may be a reason of Covariance and Contravariance but i'm not sure.

**Tip:** Also next time you add pieces of a language source code, it will be nice to know which JDK you are viewing and a link me very help.

Comment: Thanks for advice. You are right about providing a link to source code, and which JDK version that I'm taking.

Comment: I got this source code from Android SDK manager, but couldn't find which JDK version it is. Also, couldn't find a link to java framework source code.

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind that --elementCount does the assignment before decrement. That means the fragment:

```
final int index = --elementCount;
final E obj = (E) elementData[index];
elementData[index] = null;
```

Can be translated into

```
final int index = elementCount;
elementCount--;
final E obj = (E) elementData[index];
elementData[index] = null;
```

Which means in your proposed replacement "elementData[--elementCount]" and "elementData[elementCount]" do not reference the same item. Your proposed replacement is not equivalent.
Hope this helps.

Comment: `--elementCount` does the assignment after the decrement, for instance `int a=1;
int b=--a;
System.out.println(b);` will print 0.

Comment: @FlorentBayle is Right. --elementCount does the assignment AFTER decrement.